# How to copy photo attributes in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, metadata

Is there a way to copy the photo attributes in Adobe Lightroom?  Attributes would look like "Sony α6000 | 16mm | ISO 100 | f/9.0 | 1/125 sec".

I would then be able to paste along with the photo when using Instagram or other sharing sites. I could manually enter the info but would be easier to copy. I see the menu item Metadata > Copy Metadata but it does not list these attributes and all of the fields presented are blank.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the [LR/Instagram plugin](https://www.lrinstagram.com). From their [Publisher Custom Template support](https://www.lrinstagram.com/template.html) page,

> You can set the template in Publishing Manager (right click and select Edit settings to open).
>
> These custom templates are set in Publishing Manager settings
>
> The default template is "{caption} {hashtag}"

Thus, to also publish the metadata you want to show, and assuming you wanted to also publish the photo's `Caption` text, you could use the following custom template:

`{caption} {hashtag} ({cameraMake} {cameraModel} | {focalLength} | {isoSpeedRating} | {aperture} | {shutterSpeed})`

LR/Instagram is free to try, and only $10 for the full-featured registration.

See also: [*How to Post to Instagram Directly from Lightroom*](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/lightroom/instagram-publish-service-lrinstagram/) (at havecamerawilltravel.com).

Comment: $10 _*per month*_, not once.

Comment: @Aganju from the Lightroom Plug-in Manager, after adding LR/Instagram: _This plugin is distributed with a shareware model. You can try it freely, and if you find it useful, you are encouraged to pay a **one time** registration fee of $10._

Comment: You text says ‘LR/**Lightroom** is free to try, and only 10$...’ LR costs 10 per month.

Comment: @Aganju Derp, my bad. That was obviously a typo. Fixed.